# How to preview before print using eclipse?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, html, eclipse

I am using eclipse with tomcat server. My program is about to print a page containing dynamic table, which means the data and number of column even header title also dynamic. The table is continue to the next page, and i need to view the table header as well as the first page. Is there any example or page i can refer to? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: im looking for example how to do this one, i have done one. A very long code. but then cannot work. im really stuck on this right now

Comment: try something and we might help you. and it's really unclear for me what oyu want to do

Comment: i dont know which part of my code i should paste here. i have done a very long code one.

Answer (score 0):

your explanation is not clear enough but based on your question (How to preview before print using eclipse?) I think I know what you mean. as I realized you want to have a preview before printing your page, Ok then, jQuery has a plugin with this very aim which is called Print Preview Plugin. use this plugin and:

```
$('#yourcontainer').prepend('<a class="preview-page">Print this page</a>');
$('a.preview-page').printPreview();
```

then you can call `$.printPreview.loadPrintPreview();` and your problem is solved. here this is a [DEMO](http://etimbo.github.io/jquery-print-preview-plugin/example/index.html) get a view-source, you'll see the solution.

Comment: BTW, you can find this plugin's git repository in this link: [Print Preview Plugin](https://github.com/etimbo/jquery-print-preview-plugin)